# Python updating one key also updating other key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
val = {
    '1': {
      'amt': 150.0,
      'qty': 10
    }
  }

ops = {
  'add': val,
  'remove': val
}

new = {'2': {'amt': 0.0, 'qty': 5}}

ops["add"].update(new)

print(ops)
```

when you run this, the output is,

```
{'add': {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}, '2': {'amt': 0.0, 'qty': 5}}, 'remove': {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}, '2': {'amt': 0.0, 'qty': 5}}}
```

So when I update the key 'add' its also updating 'remove' with value 'new'.
I am guessing its due to the 'shallow copy' thing.
But how to handle this in better way ?

Comment: Were you helped by any of the provided answers? If so, please mark one as accepted so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `deepcopy` to copy nested mutable structures:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

ops = {'add': deepcopy(val),
       'remove': deepcopy(val)}

ops['add'].update(new)
```

Output:

```py
In [3]: ops
Out[3]:
{'add': {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}, '2': {'amt': 0.0, 'qty': 5}},
 'remove': {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}}}

In [4]: val
Out[4]: {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that `val` is the same object for both elements of ops.  Try this:

```
val = {
    '1': {
      'amt': 150.0,
      'qty': 10
    }
  }

ops = {
  'add': val.copy(),
  'remove': val.copy()
}

new = {'2': {'amt': 0.0, 'qty': 5}}

ops["add"].update(new)

print(ops)
```

Comment: Output is: {'add': {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}, '2': {'amt': 0.0, 'qty': 5}}, 'remove': {'1': {'amt': 150.0, 'qty': 10}}}